# Добавление ссылок в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Как сделать из слова ссылку по которой можно кликнуть и открыть браузер. Нужно выделить слово, нажать на `Button1` и после чего должен отобразиться `TextBox` куда вводится ссылка и по нажатию на `Button2` слово становится ссылкой. Я не знаю как прописать код на `Button2`. Как сделать из слова ссылку?

Answer (score 1):

Странный вопрос. Допустим у вас есть `string s = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"` Это строка или ссылка ?)

Если вам нужно открыть именно интернет браузер (експлорер, хром, опера, может даже амиго) и в него вбить ссылку, (потому что есть еще контролл c# `WebBrowser` для отображения интернет страниц), то нужно установить Selenium Web Driver.

Что бы получить выделенный в richTextBox участок текста воспользуйтесь свойством

> : `string s = richTextBox1.SelectedText;`

что бы добавить к выделенной строке DNS или протокол :

> textBox1.Text = "https://" + textBox1.Text + ".org";

Ну а для того что бы вывести строку в браузере используйте этот фрейм :
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Скачивиете 2 файла: драйвер (например The Internet Explorer Driver Server если хотите что бы открывалось в стандартном експлорере) и dll библиотеку которую нужно подключить к проекту.

Подключаете dll, кидаете драйвер в папку с *exe вашего проекта и добавляете код :

```
 using OpenQA.Selenium;
 ....

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string get =  textBox1.Text;

    var options = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerOptions
    {
        IgnoreZoomLevel = true
    };

    var Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver(@"pathToDriver",options); // Путь к файлу IEDriverServer.exe
    Browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.ru");
    IWebElement textbox = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
    textbox.SendKeys(get + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
}
```

или короче :

```
var Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver(@"pathToDriver",options); 
Browser.Open(get)
```